# Return nested model via intermediate model with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.6 and trying to set up a `Permissions` model to allow `Users` to access their `Projects` and their `Projects`' `Components`.  It looks like this:

**User**

```
+--------+--------+
|   id   |  uuid  |
+--------+--------+
```

**Permission**

```
+--------+-----------+--------------+
|   id   |  user_id  |  project_id  |
+--------+-----------+--------------+
```

**Project**

```
+--------+
|   id   |
+--------+
```

**Component**

```
+--------+--------------+
|   id   |  project_id  |
+--------+--------------+
```

I'd like for a query by `User` uuid to return the following format:

```
{
  id: <user.id>,
  uuid: <user.uuid>,
  projects: [
    {
      id: <project1.id>
    },
    {
      id: <project2.id>
    }
  ],
  components: [
    {
      id: <component1.id>,
      project_id: <project1.id>
    },
    {
      id: <component2.id>,
      project_id: <project2.id>
    },
    {
      id: <component3.id>,
      project_id: <project1.id>
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `projects` is determined by the `Permission` model and `components` are all the components belonging to those `projects`.

So far I have tried

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.uuid,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT row_to_json(pr.*)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        proj.id
      FROM "Projects" AS proj
      WHERE proj.id = p.project_id
    ) pr
  ) AS projects,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT row_to_json(cm.*)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        comp.id,
        comp.project_id
      FROM "Components" AS comp
      WHERE comp.project_id = p.project_id
    ) cm
  ) AS components
FROM "Users" u INNER JOIN "Permissions" p
ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.uuid = ?
```

This comes close, but it doesn't return all of the `projects` and all of the `components` that it should.

I'd appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to get it to return all `projects` that have a relevant `Permission` and all of the `components` for those `projects`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the structure I needed like so:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.uuid,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT
      row_to_json(b.*)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        prj.id
      FROM "Projects" prj
      INNER JOIN "Permissions" prm
      ON prj.id = prm.project_id
      WHERE prm.user_id = u.id
    ) b
  ) as projects,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT
      row_to_json(c.*)
    FROM (
      SELECT
        cmp.id,
        cmp.project_id
      FROM "Components" cmp
      INNER JOIN "Permissions" prm
      ON cmp.project_id = prm.project_id
      WHERE prm.user_id = u.id
    ) c
  ) as components
FROM "Users" u
WHERE u.uuid = ?
```